# Rails 4.2 to 5 update: Getting a "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I updated Rails 4.2 to 5. I followed this [article](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-5#5-application-classes)

At step 3 it asks to run the command `rails app:update`. This command changed the `secret_key_base` in all (development, test, staging and production). However in production I was setting the secret_key_base through a variable.

When I pushed the changes and tried to login I was getting this `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` error and I couldn't log in.

I decided to restore the secrets.yml file only to the old settings but the error is still there.

Any clue what is wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `protect_from_forgery`:

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
```

This is better covered in Devise README: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers